# JSONPath Expression in wso2 esb

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-integration-studio

I have a json payload that looks like below:

```
{
   "orders" : {
    "order.id" : 1024,
    "order.name" : "Ruffled-top"
}
}
```

I need to fetch order.id and order.name. Dot notation of JSONpath expression anyways won't work here. So I tried bracket notation like:

```
<property name="order-id" expression="json-eval($[orders][order.id])"/>
```

But the bracket notation is not working in wso2. Is there any other way this can be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `order.id` surrounded by `''` inside the `[]`. To access the `orders` object you can use the dot notation as well.

```xml
<property expression="json-eval($.orders.['order.id'])" name="order-id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

or

```xml
<property expression="json-eval($['orders']['order.id'])" name="order-id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```